# Use the definition of the Mean Value Theorem and definition of $f'(a)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f : [a,b] \to  \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$ . Show that if $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f'(x) = A$
then $f'(a)$ exists and equals A. [Hint: Use the definition of $f'(a)$ and the Mean Value Theorem.]

My attempt to the solution (Domain is real numbers only)

since $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f'(x) = A$ then

(1) $$\exists \sigma ,|x-a| < \sigma$$ (2)$$\forall0<\epsilon;|f'(x) - A| < \epsilon $$
for all $x$ that belong to $(a,b)$

and by MVT  $ \exists$ $c$ st. $f(b) - f(a) = f'(c)(b-a)$

now use this $c$ into $(1)$ so that

then  $(3)$ $$\exists \sigma ,|c-a| < \sigma$$ (4)$$ \forall0<\epsilon;|f'(c) - A| < \epsilon $$

and since 
$$∀ϵ;\left| \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}−f'(c)\right|<ϵ$$ (5)

I am tempted to put $4$ and $5$ together but i am not sure how to justify it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try applying MVT on $[a,a+h]$ and using the definition of the derivative at $a$

Comment: And then i just use (4) and i should be done, correct?

Comment: Yes. You actually show the limit which represents $f'(a)$ equals to $A$, and you can conclude it exists.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to post your solution as an answer to your question.